# Gradle's composite build and task dependency on artifact

Tags: gradle

Let's say I have two multiprojects:

- core/subA/moduleA (`:core:subA:moduleA`)
- impl/subB/moduleB (`:impl:subB:moduleB`)

`impl` project includes `core` as composite build.

`:impl:subB:moduleB` has dependencies like:

`implementation "core:moduleA:someVersion"`

Dependency substitution works quite well, but I need to access `"core:moduleA:someVersion"`'s jar artifact inside `:impl:subB:moduleB`'s task. While resolving dependencies, Gradle doesn't execute `assemble` task of `:core:subA:moduleA` which forces me to `dependsOn` the `:core:subA:moduleA:assemble` directly. But I found no way to do it dynamically instead of hardcoding `dependsOn gradle.includedBuild('core').task(':subA:moduleA:assemble')`.

Is there any other way how to depends on `assemble` task of the dependency?

The reason why I need that artifact is, that I wan to create `fat jar` of `:impl:subB:moduleB` with compiled classes of `:core:subA:moduleA` included and following `Jar` type task doesn't work because the artifact is not created:

`from { configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }`

Thank you.

Comment: I have exactly the same kind of issues with the composite build. I guess you would have the same in a multi project setup. Can Gradle team provide an hint about it?